# Phonegap Build Error: Xcode could not determine type of profile / No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found - Xcode 11 or Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, phonegap-build, ipa, mobileprovision

I'm trying to compile an IPA for distribution in Phonegap Build, but I'm receiving the following error:

```
Running command: xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Releva.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist /private/project/exportOptions.plist -exportPath /private/project/build/device
2020-02-19 14:42:12.285 xcodebuild[46455:98411165] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/37/x2444x712rnbshh_b1tlfwsm0000gp/T/************.xcdistributionlogs'.
2020-02-19 14:42:12.665 xcodebuild[46455:98411167]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks_Fall2018/IDEFrameworks-14460.46/IDEFoundation/Provisioning/IDEProfileQualification.m:509
Details:  Xcode could not determine type of profile "/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/production-ios-1582151957--90970.mobileprovision" (could be {(
)})
Object:   <IDEProfileQualification: 0x7fd1f6e0b350>
Method:   -_profileTypeQualifier
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd1f6806dc0>{number = 4, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
error: exportArchive: No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found

Error Domain=IDECodesignResolverErrorDomain Code=1 "No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found" UserInfo={IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorPlatform=com.apple.platform.iphoneos, IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorAction=5, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=No "iOS Distribution" signing certificate matching team ID "************" with a private key was found., IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorSpecifier=iOS Distribution, IDEProvisioningError_UserInfoKey_IDEProvisioningErrorTeam=<IDEProvisioningBasicTeam: 0x7fd1f6e0a330; teamID='***********', teamName='(null)'>, NSLocalizedDescription=No signing certificate "iOS Distribution" found}
```

I tried and retried everything with the credentials and provisioning profiles, but continue to get the same error. Creating them again and again, selecting the certificate with the private key together to export the p12, etc ..

Only thing I noticed is that when I select the certifcate to create the Provisioning Profile, it says "For use in Xcode 11 or later":

[image]

And in the error log it says "Xcode could not determine type of profile" and appears "Applications/Xcode101.app" in a lot of lines what makes me think it's trying to compile it with Xcode 10.1

What can I do for Pronegap Build to use Xcode 11 when I submit it?

Is anyone else having this issue? Any workaround to this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the problem was at the moment of creating the **certificate** in `developers.apple.com`. *(Not the Provisiotioning Profile)*

It seems Apple changed that last year, and now you have 2 options. One is Apple Distribution for Xcode 11+ and iOS (App Store and Ad Hoc) for any version.

[image]

Hope it helps anyone else having this issue.